# 3 digit 7 segment display

Tags: pins, wires, 7-segment

I have 3 digit 7 segment display with 10 pins [image: I found this image pinout]

I found this image pinout but it not working for me I need to know the pin out of this display

Comment: How do you think you have wired it? Also, do you have the datasheet for your actual device?

Comment: What is not working? How is it connected to the arduino?

Comment: make a test tool consisting of a 1.2V battery and a 2.2k ohm resistor in series with the battery .... apply one side to pin 10 and the other side to pin 7 .... if nothing lights, reverse the wires .... if nothing lights still, try other pins ..... if no lights, lower the resistor value to 1k ohm and try again

Comment: I am also get a weired 3 digit display MK5631G3 .. find its pinout and I get this ...... check this link for circuit of the display : http://ibb.co/mvvmE8
for model of the display : http://ibb.co/hdvsnT
for pinout of the Display : http://ibb.co/b5NcMo Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are supposed to multiplex this display. Put a current limiting resistor between pins 10, 8 and 6 and the arduino and all the rest can be connected directly.

First pull pin 10 low and use pins 7,9,2,3,4,1 and 5 to set the segments of the first digit.

Then put 10 high and 8 low and again use pins 7,9,2,3,4,1 and 5 to set the segments of the second digit.

repeat with pin 6 pulled low.

You can test the display with a battery and resistor. Connect them in series and put positive on the lower left pin and negative on the upper left pin. That should light up the top left vertical segment on the left most digit. You may need to turn the display around.

Comment: I believe that the problem is that the asker has found some random datasheet on the Internet that doesn't match their device, not that they don't know how to drive it (although they may *also* not know how to drive it).